# GetPivotData #REF Error, data format issue?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am getting a #Ref error when I try to reference an element from a pivottable.

I am literally doing a "=" and clicking on the pivot table to get the formula and even that is returning a #REF error.

To be a bit more specific, I am using a pivot table to sum up a datafield across some rows and columns. The columns have numbers formatted as string, so when I do the formula I get:
=getpivotdata("my_sum", ptable_ref, col_name, **"COL_VAL"**, row_name, row_val)

COL_VAL is a number like 123, 234 but formatted as a string. Right now when I do the formula for "123" it works, but the same formula for "234" gives me a #REF error. If I leave off the quotes to use the number itself, I still get an error.

I've restarted excel and my computer, but that doesn't help. The data is being pulled from a database query, but col_name is the same format for all of them. I don't see any trailing or leading spaces either. I am scratching my head about what this could be. I'd rather not have to iterate through the rows for the values I need and just use the function to make it easy on myself.

Comment: If the pivot field is a string, the value should be in quotes in `getpivotdata` (not the other way round though: you may put quotes around a number value in `getpivotdata` if the field is numeric). If it is then a `#ref`, then either the value does not exist or is not visible.

Comment: GSerg, the weird thing is that I can see the summed value in the table as we speak. Right now the table shows that for 123 the sum is 25 and for 234 the sum is 26
When I do the getpivotdata for "123" the formula returns 25
When I take the formula and just change it to "234" I get a #REF! error

Comment: Can you show a screenshot?

Comment: screenshot would be difficult due to proprietary data. If I can't figure this out, I will just have to iterate through which shouldn't be too slow, but still, it is such a weird error

Comment: Create a table with three columns with random data of the same type as your actual data. Create a pivot with the same structure from it. Format the fields in the same way. See if it reproduces there and if it does, post a screenshot of that.

Comment: Thx, but I'll just iterate for now. If I ever figure it out at some point, I will try and update. I just don't know what else a number could be stored as besides a string and why only this one version all the other ones in the table

Answer (score 0):

If some of you are looking for an error handling (#ref error might be caused by filters):

```
=if(isError(formula);defaultValue;formula)
```

In Excel you can define names/variables for long expressions, e.g

```
formula=getpivotdata("my_sum", ptable_ref, col_name, "COL_VAL", row_name, row_val)
```