# Get a Pivot Table Cell value with a formula in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

I had this formula to return the first 5 Rows from a Table to a set of cells:

```
INDEX(SUMMARY[EMPNAME],D2,1)

INDEX(SUMMARY[EMPNAME],D2+1,1)

INDEX(SUMMARY[EMPNAME],D2+2,1)

INDEX(SUMMARY[EMPNAME],D2+3,1)

INDEX(SUMMARY[EMPNAME],D2+4,1)
```

I enter 1 in D2 and it returns the first 5 rows. Change it to 6 and it will show the next 5 rows.

I now that I have the data in a Pivot Table. How do I reference the rows to accomplish the same thing?

I am trying to get the Pivot Table data in a fixed template for printing.

[image]

Comment: Try This once....If you want to refer to pivot table field absolutely without GETPIVOTDATA then remove tick from check box in File.>>Excel Options.>>Formulas.>>Working with Formulas,>>Use GetPivotData functions for PivotTable references.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53637750/getpivotdata-ref-error-data-format-issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/get-a-row-value-from-a-pivot-table.1126731/#post-5446382 for a solution to this question